# How do you graph f(x) = (-1)^x

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions

What does the graph of the function
$$
f(x) = (-1)^x
$$
look like?

It seems as if on all even $x$, $y = 1$, and on all odd $x$, $y = -1$, but between these values (fractional indices) y's value is ambiguous.

Comment: What would be the value on $x=1/2$? If you know complex numbers, then it can be extended to all $x$ in a reasonably straightforward manner.

Comment: @TMM $(-1)^{1/2}$ can be expressed as $(-1^2)^{1/4}$, which equals $1^{1/4}$, which is $\pm1$, but this is contradictory as $(-1)^{1/2}$ should obviously be $i$.

Comment: This has to do with branches of the complex logarithm: you agree on a branch, and from then on the solution is uniquely defined. It's kind of comparable to $\sqrt{4}$ being $2$ and not $-2$, by convention. Treating the square root as the inverse of the square means it is not well-defined, but by restricting the range to be the positive numbers we obtain a well-defined function.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't really look like anything. On an $(x,y)$ plot, only integer $x$ makes sense. For it to make sense continuously, if you will, we need it to take complex inputs. But this gives a 4-D graph, which we can't visualize. Sad, I know.

Comment: 1 actually has 4 distinct fourth roots. Only two are real, and two are indeed $i$ and $-i$.

Comment: @insou the expression $1^{\frac 14}$ only equals 1.

Comment: @insou $(-1^2)^{\frac 14}$ does not equal $1^{\frac 14}$.  Did you mean to write $[(-1)^2]^{\frac 14}$ instead of $(-1^2)^{\frac 14}$?  Either way, $(-1)^{\frac 12}$ cannot be written as either of those expressions because of the negative base.  Also, as another comment mentioned, the number $1$ has four 4th roots: $1$, $-1$, $i$, and $-i$.